What is the purpose of the diode in this complementary class B amplifier?
For this circuit, why did we use a diode between the bases of the two transistors?


The purpose of the diode to reduce the crossover distortion. The diodes make sure that both of the transistors base-emitter voltages to be set for linear operation.
This reduces corssover distortion because the transistors are not in the cutoff mode for part of the cycle.
